# Edittext with inputtype phone and russian letters

Tags: android, keyboard, android-inputtype

I made **edit-text** with **input type** phone in my app.

I added this into xml file:

```
 android:inputType="phone"
```

When **edit-text** is on focus, there is a keyboard with digits and English letters (2- abc, 3-def, etc.). But I need Russian letters with English near digits (2 - abc and абвг ...). How can I to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: create custom keyboard https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

Comment: The user of the device should once go to Android Settings and enable a Russian keyboard too. After that its the use who switches keyboards.